# Android Bluetooth SPP - Send/Receive data

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

I am creating an Android application where I need to connect with a Classic Bluetooth device (not BLE).

My specs say that I need to write to the Serial port some bytes to send a command to start...when I receive the answer that it started I can send another array of bytes to request for an answer from the device.

Is there any example code where I can consult to get data from my device?

Currently I open a connection to the SPP UUID service and send the bytes but I do not get anything as an answer. the device definately works as I can test it with another app.

Some snippets from my code:
(The device is not null and it is connected)

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    //UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00005500-D102-11E1-9B23-00025B00A5A5");
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
    listenForData();



void sendData(byte[] bytes) throws IOException
{
    mmOutputStream.write(bytes);
    Log.d(AppConstants.APP_TAG, "Data Sent");
}


void listenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 55; //not sure about this yet

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];

    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        Log.d(AppConstants.APP_TAG, "Found DATA!!!!");
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        Log.d(APP_TAG, data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }

        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the device expecting commands in specific format? Is there any protocol defined?you may have to check all such things. I remember some of the medical devices follow specific protocol to communicate.

Comment: @7383 Yes the device waits for a start command and the a request for specific data command. They both are HEX strings. Something like "75 89 74" which I convert to bytes[] and send them.

Comment: So looks like you are not sending the data/command correctly. Providing solutions to such problems may not be possible as the commands which you are sending to the device are proprietary. If you can give clear picture about the protocol and details on how you are sending the data might help to give answers.